# Cannot create channels with new orgs in Fabric, got error: Attempted to include a member which is not in the consortium

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Here is what I need to do in steps:

1. Create a fabric network with 2 orgs: Org1 and Org2.
2. Create a channel between them: publicchannel.
3. now add an Org3 using steps from this tutorial by fabric: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channel_update_tutorial.html
4. Create a new channel: org3org1channel, between org3 and org1.

I'm experiencing problems with step 4, it is returning:

```sh
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- Attempted to include a member which is not in the consortium
```

when I run:

```sh
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

Also, I ensure you all the paths and ENV variables are correct.

Here's my configtx.yaml file:

```
Organizations:
    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererOrg
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

    - &Org1
        Name: Org1MSP
        ID: Org1MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
              Port: 7051

    - &Org2
        Name: Org2MSP
        ID: Org2MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/bitpay.example.com/msp
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
              Port: 7051

Capabilities:
    Global: &ChannelCapabilities
        V1_1: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V1_1: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V1_2: true

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: solo
    Addresses:
        - orderer.example.com:7050
    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
    Kafka:
        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092
    Organizations:

Profiles:
    ExampleOrdererGenesis:
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            ExampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
    ExampleChannel:
        Consortium: ExampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
    TestChannel:
        Consortium: ExampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org3
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

I have created new channels with the new org, using a hack:

1. I created 2 orgs as part of the consortium: org1, org2, channelcreatororg.
2. I created a new channel named org3org1channel only consisting of org1.
3. Now I used https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channel_update_tutorial.html to make org3 join org3org1channel.

This works! But I think this is a hack because org1 was already in the genesis block definition of `ExampleConsortium`. Suppose I want to add an org4 to this network and create a channel between org4 and org3. it won't be possible. We should be able to update the consortium definition in genesis block to do so.

We should emphesise on the Profile section of the above file:

```
Profiles:
    ExampleOrdererGenesis:
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            ExampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
    ExampleChannel:
        Consortium: ExampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
    TestChannel:
        Consortium: ExampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org3
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

I think the problem is that the `ExampleOrdererGenesis` contains a consortium definition and it does not include `Org3`. Can someone help me with the steps to update it using configtxlator tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using this link: https://github.com/rohitadivi/Reconfigure-BYFN/blob/master/Create_channel.md

Make sure you understand what a `testchaninid` is within the steps of above link. We create a channel for the orderer, when we fire our genesis block transaction using `peer` command. We are fetching that channel and updating it and not any other channel.

Answer (score 1):

To add new organisation to consortium follow below steps:

```
   $: peer channel fetch config config_block.pb -o orderer.example.com:7050
    -c testchainid

   $: configtxlator proto_decode --input config_block.pb --type common.Block | jq .data.data[0].payload.data.config > config.json

   $: jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Consortiums":{"groups": {"TestConsortium": {"groups": {"Org3MSP":.[1]}}}}}}}' config.json ./org3.json > modified_config.json

   $: configtxlator proto_encode --input config.json --type common.Config
    --output config.pb

   $: configtxlator proto_encode --input modified_config.json --type common.Config --output modified_config.pb

  $:  configtxlator compute_update --channel_id testchainid --original config.pb --updated modified_config.pb --output org_update.pb

   $: configtxlator proto_decode --input  org_update.pb --type common.ConfigUpdate | jq . > org_update.json

  $:  echo '{"payload":{"header":{"channel_header":{"channel_id":"testchainid", "type":2}},"data":{"config_update":'$(cat org_update.json)'}}}' | jq . > org_update_in_envelope.json

   $: configtxlator proto_encode --input org_update_in_envelope.json --type common.Envelope --output org_update_in_envelope.pb

   $: peer channel signconfigtx -f org_update_in_envelope.pb

   $: peer channel update -f org_update_in_envelope.pb -c testchainid -o orderer.example.com:7050
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update this section everytime you add a new org into your consortium:

```
ExampleOrdererGenesis:
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            ExampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
                    - *Org3
                    - *Org4
```

Update this part in your configtx.yaml file then update the configuration using configtxlator tool as given in this tutorial https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channel_update_tutorial.html

Comment: this doesn't work as I cannot restart my network. if I could this would have been a very simple solution. See, I have already fired a genesis block transaction using `ExampleOrdererGenesis` where my consortium definition does not include Org4. Now I need a way to update this Genesis transaction.