# How to add new consortium to existing running network Hyperledger fabric?

Tags: configuration, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, channel

How to add new consortium to existing running network Hyperledger fabric?
How to add consortium and new channels?

like..

```
##Existing config
Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
                    - *Org3

##Adding new xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
             NewConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org4
##Adding
Channel14:
        Consortium: NewConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org4enter code here

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

thanks

Comment: Thk for u answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add new consortium to the running network you need to fetch and modify system channel i.e testchainid if you are using byfn. you can refer following post for steps

[Cannot create channels with new orgs in Fabric, got error: Attempted to include a member which is not in the consortium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57144745/cannot-create-channels-with-new-orgs-in-fabric-got-error-attempted-to-include/57160940#57160940).

this post is related to adding up new org to consortium in the running network only few things will change while you want to add new consortium like channel will be system channel and you need to modify jq command accordingly.

Comment: Thk for u answer.

Comment: mohammed, When we creating new consortium or new channel?

Comment: Depends how organization wants to communitcate with each other based upon there agreement they can create new consortium or new channel. you can refer following https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/network/network.html

Comment: mohammed ,To add new organisation to consortium follow below steps:  key and press in docker exec cli bash ?

Comment: can you please clarify?